# Dash reload pandas dataframe at browser reload

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have created this small simple Dash app there show 2 charts. It works but I would like to reload the data dataframe when the page are reload in the browser, because the datasource are updated each 5 min?

As I can read I need some kind of callback, any one there have example of reload the dataframe?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_json("https://URL")
data["time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["time"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
data.sort_values("time", inplace=True)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

def serve_layout():
    return  html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(children="Vejr",),
        html.P(
            children="Vejret @G12A",
        ),
        dcc.Graph(
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": data["time"],
                        "y": data["temp_air_1"],
                        "type": "lines",
                        "name": "Air temp 1",
                    },
                    {
                        "x": data["time"],
                        "y": data["temp_air_2"],
                        "type": "lines",
                        "name": "Air temp 2",
                    },
                ],
                "layout": {"title": "Temperatur"},
            },
        ),
        dcc.Graph(
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": data["time"],
                        "y": data["humidity"],
                        "type": "lines",
                        "name": "Humidity (%)",
                    },

                ],
                "layout": {"title": "Humidity"},
            },
        ),
    ]
)

app.layout = serve_layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: if any of the answers solved your question please indicate so, otherwise revise your question and wait for other replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for a real app you should be using dash dcc.Interval (https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates). The page has a nice example at the top of the page on how to create a callback to reload your resources (dataframe).

It allows you to update the visualization on an interval that you can choose. Reloading the page is an expensive operation, so I would not recommend building an app that relies on it. Unless your webpage design is dynamic, I suggest separating your static html code like in the exmaple and just use the callbacks to reload the content of the visualizations.

```
import datetime

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output



app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(children="Vejr",),
        html.P(children="Vejret @G12A"),
        dcc.Graph( id= "graph1"),
        dcc.Graph( id= "graph2") 
    ]
)


# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('graph1', 'figure'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph_live(n):
    data = {...}

    # Create the graph
    fig = plotly.Figure(.....)

    return fig
    
@app.callback(Output('graph2', 'figure'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph_live(n):
    data = {...}

    # Create the graph
    fig = plotly.Figure(.....)

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

If you don't  to build a real app and want the easier route though, then you can do what @emher suggested.

Comment: I understand your suggestion but the question was about performing operations on page reloads. In my opinion the complete answer is @emher's one with yours as a final remark

Answer (score 0):

While creating a callback is a possible solution, for your use case i would suggest simply moving the data loading into your `serve_layout` function, i.e. something like

```
def serve_layout():
    # Load the data.
    data = pd.read_json("https://URL")
    data["time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["time"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    data.sort_values("time", inplace=True)
    # Render the layout.
    return  html.Div(...)
```

Since this function is executed on pageload, you will always see up to date data.

Comment: You solution doesn't work. Maybe you mean to return html.Div(...) and data? Otherwise how can you refer to data in callbacks?

Comment: No, the function should only return the layout. If callbacks need the data, they should either load the data themselves, or read (as Input or State) from a Store object populated as part of the layout render.

Comment: @emher is there a version for multipage layouts? From the documentations, `app.layout` is assigned the `serve_layout()` function. This means upon page refresh, all the data sources would be re-queried. Is there any way to restrict this to a subset of applications in a multipage layout?